# Create faces quickly

Tags: modeling

Need to create multiple faces based on edges.

How to do it quickly?

I don't want to select every 4 edges and press `F`.

[image]

Comment: Check out `F2` Module in your Blender additional add-on

Comment: doesn't it work when you select everything then press `F`?

Comment: @wilks thanks it works fine!